# Wordpress 'Error: options page not found' when saving Custom Post Type settings

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I know this is a common error but I haven't come across any solutions that have worked. I'm creating a plugin that uses custom post types and I have a settings page under that CPT's menu. The settings page displays fine but when I go to save the settings I get the error ERROR: options page not found. Here is my settings class:

```
class Settings {
    private $view;

    public function __construct( $view ) {
        $this->view = $view;
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'submenu' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_init', function () {
            add_settings_section(
                'saw_hours',
                'Hours Settings', // Title
                array( $this, 'settings' ),
                'saw_hours_settings'
            );
        } );
    }

    public function submenu()
    {
        add_submenu_page(
            "edit.php?post_type=saw_hours", // Parent slug
            "Settings", // Page title
            "Settings", // Menu title
            "activate_plugins", // Role required
            'saw_hours_settings', // Menu slug
            array($this->view, 'admin'));
    }

    public function settings()
    {
        // API key setting
        register_setting(
            'saw_hours',
            'saw_hours_api_key'
        );
        add_settings_field(
            'saw_hours_api_key',
            'Set API Key:',
            function(){
                $clientId = get_option('saw_hours_api_key');
                echo '<input type="text" name="saw_hours_api_key" value="' . $clientId . '" >';
            },
            'saw_hours_settings',
            'saw_hours'
        );

        // Client ID setting
        register_setting(
            'saw_hours',
            'saw_hours_client_id'
        );
        add_settings_field(
            'saw_hours_client_id',
            'Set Client ID:',
            function(){
                $clientId = get_option('saw_hours_client_id');
                echo '<input type="text" name="saw_hours_client_id" value="' . $clientId . '" >';
            },
            'saw_hours_settings',
            'saw_hours'
        );
    }


}
```

And here is the form page:

```
<form method="POST" action="options.php">
  <?php settings_fields( 'saw_hours' ); ?>
  <?php do_settings_sections( 'saw_hours_settings'); ?>
  <?php submit_button(); ?>
</form>
```

I'm at a loss, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer here:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139660/error-options-page-not-found-on-settings-page-submission-for-an-oop-plugin

This doesn't really answer why register_setting() isn't adding the property to the list of whitelisted properties. If anyone has a better understanding of what's going here I'd love to hear.